# Debugging a running python process

Tags: python, debugging

I want to debug a running python service which has threads in my Ubuntu system. I need to attach running root process and be able to place break points in python script.

What would be the best way to follow for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python debugger, `pdb`, for this. You can import it as a module or use it interactively. The docs for 2.7 are here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: Would you mind to detail a little more how to use `pdb`?

Comment: pdb can be used when the program is run from the console. In case of a service, pdb would interrupt the execution but you don't get a console prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can use my project [madbg](https://github.com/kmaork/madbg). It is a python debugger that allows you to attach to a running python program and debug it in your current terminal. It is similar to `pyrasite` and `pyringe`, but supports python3, doesn't require gdb, and uses `IPython` for the debugger (which means pdb with colors and autocomplete).

For example, to see where your script is stuck, you could run:

```
madbg attach <pid>
```

And in the debugger shell, enter:
`bt`